# SQL variable within function

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I have this pretty basic query, with a not so basic compound.

In the little script I'm making, I'm allowing the user to choose between two values. those values will make the "where" change. that part i can figure out, if `Variable=xyz` then `OtherVariable=abc`.

The issue is that I want to use that as a complete "where" change. Let me try to explain with code:

If the user chooses the variable A the where is

`Where (LineTi<>0) AND (LEFT(Tbl_Cli.Num,1) like '5' )`

BUT if the user chooses B, the where becomes

`(intTpLinha<>0) AND (LEFT(Tbl_Clientes.strNumContrib,1) NOT like '5' )`

Any tips on how to do this? can I change just the "like" part and put it in a variable?

Something like this:

`(intTpLinha<>0) AND (LEFT(Tbl_Clientes.strNumContrib,1) @Variable)`

Thank you for the help

I've tried what I previously mentioned, to no avail

Comment: Not in function - you need dynamic sql for such kind of replacement and dynamic sql is not allowed. In stored proceduers it would be OK.

Comment: Just use an equality test. There's no reason for `like`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the user chooses the variable A then the `where` clause is ... but if the user chooses B, the it becomes ...

You seem to be looking for the following boolean logic:

```
WHERE ( @Variable = 'A' AND LineTi     <> 0 AND Tbl_Cli.Num     LIKE '5%' )
   OR ( @Variable = 'B' AND intTpLinha <> 0 AND Tbl_Cli.Num NOT LIKE '5%' )
```

The `where` clause is made of two `OR`ed predicates, each being specific to the value of `@Variable`. Note that I simplified the condition on column `Tbl_Cli.Num`, to use `LIKE` only and not `LEFT`.

Comment: The "if" part i can manage, its the part of changing the Where im stumped.

I dont want both. i want to only filter one or the other, not a or

Comment: Both predicates are exclusive (typically because `@Variable` has different values), so no row can match on both predicates.

Comment: @HélderCarneiro, to add to GMB's answer, SQL Server will eliminate the unnecessary `OR` condition if you add an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. If you view the actual execution plan with the hint, you'll see only one of the predicates are in the plan because the `@Variable` value was evaluated at compile time. The hint may be used as a query optimization technique for `OR` conditions.

Comment: This did indeed solve my problem, with some tweaks, but it ended up serving my case!

before the select i did a find what variable the user choose
 set @Text= CASE when @tipEnt = 'Particular' THEN 4 else 5 end

then in the where i did

AND (
   
    (@Text = 5 AND (LEFT(Tbl_Table.Field,1) like '5'))
  OR (@Text != 5 AND (LEFT(Tbl_Table.Field1) NOT like '5')))